# Do HP increasing items work in Hardcore mode?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

In the shop there's a Hardcore mode that sets your HP to 1. What happens if you get an HP increasing item like Just Bandage or Piki Piki Piman while Hardcore mode is enabled? Do they have any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Taking Just Bandage or Piki Piki Piman during Hardcore mode will not affect your maximum HP. This also applies to the HP decreasing/draining items Energy Drink and Injection Type Asacoco, which can essentially be taken without concequence.

In contrast, the shield item Body Pillow will still absorb damage, allowing you to take multiple hits in Hardcore mode.

[image: HP increasing items not increasing HP]